# Why isn't a local function getting assigned to the global object (window)?

Tags: javascript

```js
function globaltest() {
  this.proptest = "SOMETHING";
  alert(this.proptest);
}
```

The 'globaltest' function gets automatically assigned as a method to the `Window` object, and I can trigger it from there. `Window.globaltest()` works. `This` keyword refers to the `window` object. The proptest property also gets assigned to the `Window` object, because I am assigning it to `this` keyword.

But, if I create a local function inside this function, and assign it to `This` keyword, which should refer to the global object, it doesn't work.

```js
function globaltest() {
  this.proptest = function() {
    var insidetest = 2 + 2;
    alert(insidetest);
  }
}

window.proptest();
```

It's not working. Why? Isn't the local function getting assigned to `This`, which refers to the `Window` object? Apparently not, because the console says that `window.proptest` is not a function. But why? Did I not assign it to the global object using the `this` keyword? Why did it work when assigning a property with a string value, but not when assigning another local function to it?

**NOTE** I just found out that the first snippet is not working here, but is working just fine as expected on my computer. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Did you run globaltest function before?

Comment: Also keep in mind, that if you run it in strict mode, none of the two will work as you cannot reference the global `window` through `this`.

Comment: @MathKimRobin Yes, it works on my computer just fine. Why?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli But i thought that, the 'this' keyword references the parent object, which is the global object until you assign it to another one.

Comment: @MathKimRobin Why is the first snippet not working here, but working fine on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function globaltest() {
    this.proptest = function() {
    var insidetest = 2 + 2;
    alert(insidetest);
    }
}

window.proptest();
```

The first task javascript does is that it takes the function and stores it as it is.
Now your function inside this function is never called.
If you call the outer function, then it will work fine, it will add the innner function to the this object(window object here)

Comment: But I am calling the window.proptest() function, but so why is it not getting triggered? It says that the window.proptest() is not a function. How come? Did it not got assigned to the global object?

Comment: because it is not created yet

Comment: Do you mean that, the local function is not assigned yet, because the parent function has not been triggered yet?

Comment: I just tested it. I triggered the global function first, and then the local one and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in your example, you call only this one

```
proptest
```

and don't call

```
globaltest
```

This will works better

```js
function globaltest() {
  this.proptest = function() {
    var insidetest = 2 + 2;
    alert(insidetest);
  }
}

window.globaltest() 
window.proptest();
```

And remember that this is window/global **only** in non-strict mode. In strict mode, this refers to undefined in a non-object context.

Comment: Yeah, i already tested this and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Do you mind me asking you another question, unrelated to this one, or should I post another question all together?

Comment: Post another question please. It will be more easy for anybody to find the answer later.